# How to get the several data from each group on query builder laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

a16s table

```
id  p_id u_id   time
1   1       2   0
2   1       1   1
3   1       5   2
4   1       6   3
5   1       7   4
6   2       2   2
7   2       3   1
8   2       1   0
9   3       2   11
10  3       4   8
11  3       8   15
```

I want to get
the first two data orderby time from each group

```
p_id u_id time
1     2   0
1     1   1
2     1   0
2     3   1
3     4   8
3     2   11
```

I try the query

```
  $result = DB::table('a16s')

            ->select ('p_id','u_id','time'))
            ->orderBy('time', 'desc')
            ->groupBy('p_id')
            ->get();

    echo '<pre>' ;
    print_r($result);
```

I got the error
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column...

Can I use groupby twice? I Want to get this result to use on the jquery datatable.

from the database

```
id  p_id    u_id    approve time
1   1          1    1       1
2   1          2    1       2
3   1          3    1       3
4   1          4    0       4
5   1          5    0       5
6   2          1    0       1
7   2          2    1       2
8   2          5    0       3
9   2          6    0       4
10  3          2    1       1
11  3          5    1       2
12  3          8    1       3
```

to get the table
[image]

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229955/laravel-database-strict-mode/49230235#49230235

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$result = DB::table('a16s')
            ->select('p_id', 'u_id', 'time')
            ->orderBy('time', 'desc')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('p_id')
            ->map(function ($deal) {
                return $deal->take(2);
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! Can I add one column to group twice ? I ammend my question above.  I try  ->get()->groupBy('p_id')->group('approve')->.... But not work.

Comment: if you want to group multiple columns you can  ->groupBy('p_id' , '2nd Column')

Comment: I tried groupBy('p_id','approve')  but I  only got the group1 first two rows just like : group1(p_id=1)  -group2(approve-1)-u_id1 and u_id(2row) ,no got the group1(p_id=1)-group2(approve-0)-u_id4 and u_id5 (2rows) ? Where can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

With your SQL version, `u_id` will either need to be left out of the select or added to the `GROUP BY` clause.

See this [MySql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15585351/4848587):

```php
$join = DB::table('a16s')->select('p_id')
    ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(time ORDER BY time ASC) times')->groupBy('p_id');
$sql = '(' . $join->toSql() . ') latest';
$result = DB::table('a16s')
    ->select('a16s.*')
    ->join(DB::raw($sql), function($join) {
        $join->on('a16s.p_id','=','latest.p_id');
        $join->whereBetween(DB::raw('FIND_IN_SET(`a16s`.`time`, `latest`.`times`)'), [1, 2]);
    })
    ->get();
```